# How to use shader for postprocessing?

Tags: directx-10

Assume that I render a frame to a texture (YUY2 format), how can I use shader for YUY2->RGB processing? The idea is to get RGB for the render target output, but the GPU should handle the conversion.

Comment: Direct3D 10 does not support working with video formats. DirectX 11.1 includes DirectX 11 Video which lets you 'cast' video formats and maps them to 'standard' formats which lets you operate on planar video textures in HLSL shaders. See [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/hh447677.aspx) and [this sample](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-classic-samples/tree/master/Samples/DX11VideoRenderer)

Comment: That example includes MF which brings a whole pile of additional complexity. I would like to stay away from it and stick to the D3D only. Thanks for the DX10 vs DX11 info!